# Typescript - Object display correct datas but properties are undefined on access

Tags: typescript, object, properties, undefined

When I log the entire object all the datas are displayed but when I try to access the properties they are undefined. As if the object's properties where not mapped to their datas.

A component containing the data :

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.scss'],
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit, ISimulable {
  ...

  cardData?: ICardData;
  
  ...

  constructor(
    private simulationService: SimulationService,
    private dispatcher: DataDispatcherService
  ) {}
  
  ...

  getData(): void {
    var temp = this.dispatcher.getCardDataFromType(this.cardDataClass, {
      timestamp: '2021/10/10', model: this.radioValue as DataModels, distribution: 
      this.radioValue as DataDistributions
    });
    this.cardData = temp.rawData as ICardData;
    console.log(temp);
    console.log(temp.rawData);
  }

  ...
```

The console output :
[image: result of logs]

The class displayed :

```js
export class BoshGasDataCardDispatcher extends ADispatchedData {

  constructor(storageService: DataStorageService, input: ICardDispatchInput) {
    super(storageService, input);
  }

  /**
   * @param {DataStorageService} storageService The service fetching data.
   * @param {ICardDispatchInput} input The data used to fetch raw data.
   */
  protected async selectData(storageService: DataStorageService, input: ICardDispatchInput): Promise<void> {
    var tempData: ICalculation = await storageService.getCalculation(input.timestamp);
    var tempTranslation: ILanguageSettings = await storageService.getTranslationData("en-GB");

    var tempCard: ICardData = {title: tempTranslation.texts['Raceway_boshGasGroupBox_Text'], rows:[]};

    tempCard.rows.push({
      label: placeholder,
      value: placeholder,
      simValue: placeholder,
      unit: placeholder
    } as ICardRowData);

    tempCard.rows.push({
      label: placeholder,
      value: placeholder,
      simValue: placeholder,
      unit: placeholder
    } as ICardRowData);

    tempCard.rows.push({
      label: placeholder,
      value: placeholder,
      simValue: placeholder,
      unit: placeholder
    } as ICardRowData);
 
    tempCard.rows.push({
      label: placeholder,
      value: placeholder,
      simValue: placeholder,
      unit: placeholder
    } as ICardRowData);

    tempCard.rows.push({
      label: placeholder,
      value: placeholder,
      simValue: placeholder,
      unit: placeholder
    } as ICardRowData);
 
    tempCard.rows.push({
      label: placeholder,
      value: placeholder,
      simValue: placeholder,
      unit: placeholder
    } as ICardRowData);

    this.rawData = tempCard;
  }
}
```

The extended abstract class :

```js
import { DataStorageService } from "../../core/services/data-storage.service";

export abstract class ADispatchedData{

  rawData: any;

  constructor(storageService: DataStorageService, input: any) {
    this.selectData(storageService, input);
  }

  /**
   * Fill rawData with the necessary data for the creating component.
   * @param {DataStorageService} storageService The service fetching data.
   * @param {any} input The data used to fetch raw data.
   */
  protected abstract selectData(storageService: DataStorageService, input: any): void;
}
```

ICardData file :

```js
import { ICardRowData } from './card-row-data.interface';
export interface ICardData{
  readonly title: string;
  readonly rows: ICardRowData[];
  message?: string;
}
```

ICardRowData file :

```js
export interface ICardRowData{

  readonly label: string;

  readonly value: number | string;

  simValue: number | string;

  readonly unit: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the implementations of the abstract class. I was adding the `async` keyword to the `selectData` method since it's not possible to add it on the abstract original one. However that isn't enough to cause my problem, what really f****d it up was to call that method in the constructor of the abstract class. To solve this I had to remove that call from the constructor and put it somewhere else.

Abstract class :

```js
import { DataStorageService } from "../../core/services/data-storage.service";

export abstract class ADispatchedData{

  rawData: any;

  constructor(protected storageService: DataStorageService, input: any) {
   // Removed the call to selectData
   // Put the service as protected to avoid redundancy and ease the use of selectData
  }

  abstract selectData(input: any): Promise<void>; 
  // Added the Promise<void> for consistency
  // Removed the service from the parameters, now a protected property 
}
```

Example of an implementation :

```js
...

export class OxycoalCardDispatcher extends ADispatchedData {

  constructor(storageService: DataStorageService, input: ICardDispatchInput) {
    super(storageService, input);
  }

  async selectData(input: ICardDispatchInput): Promise<void> {
    var tempData: ICalculation = await this.storageService.getCalculation(input.timestamp);
    var tempTranslation: ILanguageSettings = await this.storageService.getTranslationData("en-GB");

    var tempCard: ICardData = {title: tempTranslation.texts["Raceway_OxyCoalGroupBox_Text"], rows:[]};

    tempCard.rows.push({
      label: placeholder,
      value: placeholder,
      simValue: placeholder,
      unit: placeholder
    } as ICardRowData);

    this.rawData = tempCard;
  }
}
```

Where the call is now done :

```js
async getCardDataFromType(dataClass: Type<ADispatchedData>, input: ICardDispatchInput): Promise<ADispatchedData> {
    var temp = new dataClass(this.storageService, input);
    await temp.selectData(input);
    return temp;
  }
```